# Mounting USB-B connector off-board in device enclosure. Is there a standard component for this?

Tags: usb, pcb-assembly

So I'm working on a PCB that I'm hoping to quote for production.  It makes sense to put all the control and output features on a single PCB, and that's generally the plan.  However, the power jack (Mini-B socket) has to be about 2" away at the back of the enclosure.  Its the only thing that needs to be back there.  I'll have a little rechargeable battery in between the two, and the charging circuit will be built into said PCB in front.  Is there a standard "tethered" USB socket that I can just have soldered to the PCB at the factory?  I was thinking just a simple wire connection, but maybe a rigid stamped pin connector, or ribbon would work.

Comment: Please make your question a little more specific, its a unclear what you need to accomplish. The other problem with this question is if your asking for a recommendation on what to get those questions generally get shut down. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Okay.  I need to attach a female mini-b  socket 2" away from my main PCB inside an enclosure.

Comment: Not to complicate my question, but of course I could just chop the end off a standard cable and wire the two power leads to my PCB and the assembly would work.  As a non-EE professional, I'm asking what the professional approach would be.  Of the connectors and wiring solutions I've found none seem intended to be used inside an enclosure as a "remotely tethered" component.

Comment: @Kevin, how do you plan so secure the "mini-B" receptacle in your enclosure, even if you find some odd extender? You will need some custom molding, mounts, or something. Typically people make a separate small PCB, and solder a regular mini-USB (or whatever) receptacle on it, and use a cable. Since you plan for power-only, this should be not very ugly. An odd-shape main PCBs is also a frequent solution in portable devices.

Comment: Typically the receptacles have little arms that reach out.  I was just going to mold in some features to the clamshell enclosure to secure it.  I guess I just thought there would be a standard cheap component with wires coming off of it.  This is meant to be a low cost product.  Many of these solutions are cost prohibitive.  If I have to make a separate daughter board, I think I will just make two pcbs joined with a ribbon.  That was always the other possibility.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite often the case that you need to mount connectors to enclosures in a separate part from the main PCB, and there are a couple of options of doing this.

1. If you can get hold of connector of the correct type which is "Chassis Mount" or "Panel Mount", then you can go down that route. Typically these connectors mount into the case using some form of bolt or screw. You can get many switches in this form, but also quite a few standard connectors like USB and Ethernet along with barrel jacks. As an example:

   [image: Panel Mount USB Example]

   For cases which are expected to be exposed to the elements or be otherwise used outside, typically you want to get one with a suitable [IP rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code). These tend to be bulkier but are more rugged.

   [image: Rugged USB]
2. The other option is you go for your chosen connector in a PCB mount variant and then make a small daughter board. Basically the board contains the connector, some mount holes for screwing it to the case or other support structure, and a second internal cable connection to go back to your main board. This is typically the sort of board you find in computer cases amongst others as it is usually the cheapest approach (chassis connectors can be pricy).

   An example would be the front panel connection PCBs that are in most computer cases:

   [image: Front Panel PCB]